# Were there high-ranking Japanese POW as witness at the Trinity Atomic Bomb Test?

Tags: world-war-two, japan, hiroshima

One argument was that providing a demonstration on an unpopulated island ran the risk of failure in front of Japanese observers. But I have not read any suggestion of using a Japanese POW of high officer rank being an observer at the Trinity test. If the bomb worked he could have been released and if it failed, not released.

I assume that Japanese POWs who were officers might have been few but I would guess there were some.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I'm confused as to the basis of this question. That was a top-secret project during wartime, and I've never heard of anything like this happening with any wartime weapon systems test in history. What makes you think this is a thing that might have happened in this one particular case?

Comment: @T.E.D.: There was a suggestion to do a demo for the Japanese military with the drawback being the case of failure. But using a POW who presumably would be believed if released but importantly did not have to be released would seem to address the case of failure.

Comment: "there was a suggestion" - history without sources is like physics without units; valid for personal amusement, but utterly useless.  If you choose to conceal your sources, then I would vote to close as a hypothetical unrelated to actual history.

Comment: Ah! OK, that would be a very good thing (with all the details about said suggestion) to edit in the question. We aren't very good with "I heard somewhere" statements, but its even worse when its an absolute mystery why such a thing would be asked.

Comment: @T.E.D.: anyone who could answer this question would have read, for example, The Making of the Atomic Bomb which discusses alternatives to bombing a populated area.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about actual history but rather about "one idea", not placed in a context specifying _who_ had this idea, or _when_.

Comment: Given that it's the Japanese we're talking about, the first thing I'd check is if the Allies had captured *any* high ranking Japanese officers.

Comment: @kimchilover: definitely a history question. we know that a demo was suggested; what we don't know if where a demo to a POW Japanese officer was suggested.

Comment: It's a question about the past, I'll grant you.  History is the _study_ of the past; what have you studied about this question?  What does Richard Rhoads's book say about this question?

Comment: @releseabe The problem with "did X consider Y" is because it is *speculation about a suggestion*. Maybe somebody happens to know, but otherwise it is effectively unanswerable without a full archive search. That requires some prior research. Consider contacting the Atomic Heritage Foundation or the National Atomic Test Museum.

Comment: @schwern: I wonder about that also: not many Japanese officers probably were captured and above a certain level, like captain perhaps, zero. They might have found a soldier with a science background, even if a non-officer.

Comment: @schwern: I am not asking what someone thought; I am asking what is documented. I have not seen this suggestion and I have read extensively -- while it seems like a reasonable thing to consider, perhaps no one did suggest it or maybe there literally were no qualified POWs to use as a witness. But it is a valid history question, I am convinced of that.

Comment: @releseabe And that's where the [evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question/3227#3227) comes in. What searching have you done? The documentation of a suggestion will require an archive search. You've been given some suggestions where to start. Send some emails and make some phone calls.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP refuses to do the research themselves.

Comment: The premise of the question seems to be that the OP believes that the USA used the atomic bombings to force Japan to surrender, instead of being a mean to test this new expensive toy they had and signal a warning to the Soviet Union. Several naïve scientists of the Manhattan project suggested that kind of "demonstration only" detonations. The military never had any intention of doing that.

Answer (score 4):

The question of whether this was *suggested* can only be answered by a full archive search. The question of whether this was *done* is a bit easier to check, there's probably a list of witnesses to Trinity somewhere, which can be dug up. I have never seen mention nor suggestion of this. You can contact the [Atomic Heritage Foundation](https://www.atomicheritage.org/) and the [National Atomic Test Museum](https://nationalatomictestingmuseum.org/) for a more definitive answer.

What is easier to ask is *was this even possible*? It's predicated on two things: the Allies having high-ranking Japanese POWs, and the Allies believing the Japanese would listen.

## Japanese attitudes on surrender

Unlike Western armies who believed you fought until it was hopeless and then surrendered (and tried to escape), Imperial Japan did not believe in surrender. They did not ratify the [Geneva Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_Convention_(1929)).

Given that surrender was considered a great dishonor, would the Japanese even listen to a POW? Given that the US only had three bombs, was it worth using one for a demonstration only to have the Japanese ignore the POW's story?

Here's a few samples about death and surrender from their [Senjinkun military code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senjinkun_military_code).

*From "Discipline"*

> The spirit of the soldier is best exemplified by those who silently do their duty, joyfully braving death in obedience to a command given at a time when they are undergoing great hardships.

*From "Unity"*

> It is essential that each man, high and low, dutifully observing his place, should be determined always to sacrifice himself for the whole, in accordance with the intentions of the commander, by reposing every confidence in his comrades, and without giving even the slightest thought to personal interest and to life or death.

*From "Aggressiveness"*

> In defence, always retain the spirit of attack an always maintain freedom of action; never give up a position but rather die.

*From "The Conviction To Win"*

> Do not give up under any circumstances, keeping in mind your responsibility to keep untarnished the glorious history of the Imperial Army with its tradition of invincibility.

*From "View Of Life And Death"*

> Do your duty with heart and soul, regardless of life or death. After exerting all your powers, spiritually and physically, calmly face death rejoicing in the hope of living in the eternal cause for which you serve.

*From "Honour"*

> Meet the expectation of your family and home community by making effort upon effort, always mindful of the honour of your name. If alive, do not suffer the disgrace of becoming a prisoner; in death, do not leave behind a name soiled by misdeeds.

*[Source: Senjinkun (1941) translated into English by the Tokyo Gazette Publishing House](https://nla.gov.au/nla.obj-372598481/view?partId=nla.obj-372600030#page/n0/mode/1up)*

## Did the Allies capture any high ranking Japanese POWs?

This is the part which can be checked with some research to find a definitive list of Japanese POWs in captivity prior to the Hiroshima bombing. Here's what a quick search turned up...

[Vice Admiral Shigeru Fukudome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shigeru_Fukudome) was the first Japanese flag officer to be captured by the enemy in March 1944. He was captured by Filipino guerillas and released to avoid retaliation on civilians. Fukudome continued his career despite being captured, perhaps because it was during a plane crash, not battle.

[Ensign Kazuo Sakamaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuo_Sakamaki), technically an officer, was found unconscious after his failed midget submarine attack on Pearl Harbor.

And that's about all I can find.

Comment: Feynman's memoir [Surely You're Joking Mr. Feynman](https://chem.fsu.edu/chemlab/isc3523c/feyn_surely.pdf) details his experience of the Trinity test (search "Trinity") including: "*... I arrived just when the buses were leaving, so I went straight out to the site and we waited out there, twenty miles away. ... The man was William Laurence. He was there to write an article describing the whole situation.*" If a Japanese POW had been witness, someone if not the reporter would have noted it. Security was mostly the sheer isolation of Los Alamos at that time.